# password Ruby on Rails Tutorial by M. Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've just started using rails, and decided to follow the "*Ruby on Rails Tutorial*" by M. Hartl. Seems like a good intro.

**Am running into a failed test** that's driving me nuts.
I am running **rails 3.1.1**, with **rspec 2.7.0**

I have tried modifying the condition, and tests on the "has_password" method work.

The failing test:

```
1) User password encryption authenticate method should return the user on email/password match
Failure/Error: matching_user.should == @user
 expected: #
      got: nil (using ==)
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:149:in `block (4 levels) in '
```

The rspec test:

```
describe User do

before(:each) do
@attr = {:name => 'testing', 
         :email =>'testing@example.com',
         :password => "testtest",
         :password_confirmation => "testtest"}
end

...

describe "password encryption" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!(@attr)
  end

...

describe "authenticate method" do

  it "should exist" do
    User.should respond_to(:authenticate)
  end

  it "should return nil on email/password mismatch" do
    User.authenticate(@attr[:email], "wrongpass").should be_nil
  end

  it "should return nil for an email address with no user" do
    User.authenticate("bar@foo.com", @attr[:password]).should be_nil
  end

  it "should return the user on email/password match" do
    matching_user = User.authenticate(@attr[:email], @attr[:password])
    matching_user.should == @user
  end      
end
```

In the User model:

```
...

def has_password?(submitted_password) 
  encrypt_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
  user = find_by_email(email) #self.where("email = ?", email) 
  return nil if user.nil?
  return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end

private

 def encrypt_password
   self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
   self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
 end
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This book also has a forum, apparently. That helped as well:
http://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your failing spec you have

```
matching_user.should == @user
```

But `@user` isn't defined anywhere so it's set to nil.

**Edit:**

Try adding the following `puts` into the failing spec and see what results you get in your spec output after running it.

```
it "should return the user on email/password match" do
  matching_user = User.authenticate(@attr[:email], @attr[:password])
  puts matching_user  # add this
  puts @user          # and also this
  matching_user.should == @user
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I originally omitted the code that created the user due to this post's length. I added it. Still same problem.

Comment: Thanks! With your debugging help, I found that my has_password method had a typo: 

`def has_password?(submitted_password) 
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end`